# How to find a string within a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array like this:

```
'10 Hz: Time_abs'
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
'10 Hz: Time_abs'
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
<1x2 cell>
```

At first I need to find in which rows there is `10 Hz: Time_abs` and then delete the corresponding row.
I cannot use `strcmp` because the other rows are `<1x2 cell>`.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Don't you mean `{1x2 cell}` instead? If so, `strcmp` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate cell by cell and check for being string using `isstr` function, for instance:

```
A{1} = 'sdadfadf';
A{2} = 23;
A{3} = [1,2,3,4];
A{4} = 0;


for ii=1:length(A)
isstr(A{ii})
end

ans =  1
ans = 0
ans = 0
ans = 0
```

The other solution is using `ischar` function:

```
C{1,1} = magic(5);
C{1,2} = 'John Dump';
C{1,3} = 1 + 1i     
C{1,4} = 0.0025

for k = 1:4
x(k) = ischar(C{1,k});
end

x

x =

     0     1     0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
C{1,1} = magic(5);
C{1,2} = 'John Dump';
C{1,3} = 1 + 1i     
C{1,4} = 0.0025

x = cellfun(@ischar, C)

x =

     0     1     0    0
```